# Using HTML Divs to Make Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css

I'm just starting web development, and I'm trying to construct a page-navigation bar with a bunch of 'Div' elements, but I cant seem to get my second button ("AboutButton") to appear on the screen. Here is my HTML body code:

```
<body>

    <div id="navbar" id="top">
        <div id="pageselection">
            <div id="HomeButton"> <a href="#top"> HOME </a> </div>
            <div id="AboutButton"> <a href="#About> ABOUT </a> </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
```

and here is my CSS for the page:

```
#navbar{
Position: fixed;
Width: 100%;
Height: 10%;
}

#pageselection{
Position: absolute;
Width: 40%;
Height: 100%;
Right: 30%;
}

#HomeButton{
Position: absolute;
Width: 33%;
Height: 100%;
Left: 0%;
text-align: center;
}

#AboutButton{
Position: absolute;
Width: 33%;
Height: 100%;
Left: 33%;
text-align: center;
}
```

Essentially, I'm trying to build a 'div' that runs across the top of the page, then mark off the central 40% of that 'div' as a space for a second 'div' to sit, which will in turn hold the three links that users can use to navigate the page.

Thanks in advance, hopefully its a stupid error, and I hope my description was clear enough :)

Comment: Bootstrap may help you

Comment: Bootstrap is a tool to be used, but it doesn't help a pure beginner learn any of the fundamentals of markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed an quote mark in

```
<a href="#About>
```

If you are only starting, i recommend you to use some free editors like [Atom](https://atom.io) or [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/) that will alert you about this kind of errors.

Also, it is not allowed to use "id" two times on an element. A better practice would be to use [classes](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp) where you will be able to stack them like:

```
<div class="navbar top"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. About not using "id" twice on an element, does that mean I can't identify an element with "id" if its already within another element that has been identified with an "id"?

Comment: "id" is a unique identifier, it can be only used once in the entire html page.
You can insert an "id" inside another "id"

Comment: A little clarification is needed here: You cannot use `id` more than once on the same element. You can use it more than one throughout your entire markup; however, you may only use each unique identifier one time.

Comment: Oh I just realized that I assigned my big div two different id statements. My bad, I understand what you guys are saying. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You missed an ending quote `"` in `<a href="#About>`. I also recommend another approach on your nav bar. Don't absolute position the links in the nav bar, that's not needed. And also, one element can have one ID, not multiple. I've made some changes and used classes instead of IDs below. Please have a look.

```css
#navbar{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  height: 40px;
}

#pageselection{
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  right: 30%;
  background-color: gray;
}

.nav-button{
  float:left;
  width:33%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height:40px;
}
.nav-button a{
  display:block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar" id="top">
    <div id="pageselection">
        <div class="nav-button"><a href="#top">HOME</a></div>
        <div class="nav-button"><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></div>
        <div class="nav-button"><a href="#test">TEST</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```